# How to rotate two game objects together?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I have a game where you need to rotate clocks.I cant figure out how to rotate two or more clock arrows toghether.Arrows are not on the same clock.Arrows have diffrent rotations and they have to keep their rotation diffrences.I.E one arrow is 180 another 90 so after 90 degree turn fist one should be 270 and another one 180.Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MoveClock : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject root;
public Transform arrow;
public CircleCollider2D circleCollider;
public BoxCollider2D boxColliderTrigger;
public List<MoveClock> connectedClocks;
public GameManger gameManager;
public BoxCollider2D[] colliders;
public int n;
public BoxCollider2D[] disabledTriggers;
public bool equal;
const float initialValue = 90;
static public int k;

public float angle;
public float snapAngle;
public float dif;
public Vector3 mousepos;
public Vector3 dir;
public int[] zAngles;
void Start()
{
    zAngles = new int[n];
    SetAngles();
    CalculateDiffrence();
}
void Update()
{
}
public void MoveArrow(out float snapAngle)
{
    snapAngle = 0;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        dir = transform.position - mousepos;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + initialValue;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        snapAngle = SnapAngle(angle);
        SetAngleTo(angle);
    }
}
private void SetAngles()
{
    int angle = 360 / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        zAngles[i] = angle * i;
    }
}
private float SnapAngle(float target)
{
    float minDiffrence = float.MaxValue;
    float closest = float.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < zAngles.Length; i++)
    {
        float diff = Mathf.Abs(zAngles[i] - target);
        if (minDiffrence > diff)
        {
            minDiffrence = diff;
            closest = zAngles[i];
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
public void SetAngleTo(float a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < connectedClocks.Count; i++)
    {
        if(equal==true)
            connectedClocks[i].arrow.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(a, Vector3.forward);
        else
            connectedClocks[i].arrow.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(a + connectedClocks[i].dif, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
public void CalculateDiffrence()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < connectedClocks.Count; i++)
    {
        Vector3 dir = connectedClocks[i].transform.position - transform.position;
        dir = connectedClocks[i].transform.InverseTransformDirection(dir);
        dif = SnapAngle(Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg+initialValue);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("{0} {1}", dif, connectedClocks[i].circleCollider.name));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's arguably easier to do this sort of thing as parenting objects to one another in the Editor.  That way you can just adjust the transform for an arrow without affecting the other. If you rotate the clock however, the arrows move with it.

Comment: are you using global or local space?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put one of the object as the child of another, that will do.

```
A         //or   B
|__B      //     |__A
```

Or programmatically:

```
A.transform.parent = B.transform; //or
A.transform.SetParent(B.transform);
```

In this setting, if you rotate A any angles, B will follow and no need to calculate and keep their angle difference in code.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that.I might overthought it as always

Comment: Forgot to mention that arrows are on diffrent clocks